# Increase speed of OpenCL image processing

Tags: image-processing, kernel, opencl

I think the execution time of my kernel is too high. It's job is it to just blend two images together using either addition, subtraction, division or multiplication.

```
#define SETUP_KERNEL(name, operator)\
 __kernel void name(__read_only image2d_t image1,\
                        __read_only image2d_t image2,\
                       __write_only image2d_t output,\
                       const sampler_t sampler1,\
                       const sampler_t sampler2,\
                       float opacity)\
{\
    int2 xy = (int2) (get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));\
    float2 normalizedCoords = convert_float2(xy) / (float2) (get_image_width(output), get_image_height(output));\
    float4 pixel1 = read_imagef(image1, sampler1, normalizedCoords);\
    float4 pixel2 = read_imagef(image2, sampler2, normalizedCoords);\
    write_imagef(output, xy, (pixel1 * opacity) operator pixel2);\
}

SETUP_KERNEL(div, /)
SETUP_KERNEL(add, +)
SETUP_KERNEL(mult, *)
SETUP_KERNEL(sub, -)
```

As you can see I use macros to quickly define the different kernels. (Should I better use functions for that?)
Somehow the kernel managed to take 3ms on a GTX 970.
What can I do to increase the performance of this particular kernel?
Should I split it into different programs?

Comment: whats the size of image?

Comment: 2048 x 2048 pixels.

Comment: is this opengl-opencl shared image? not copied from host or copied?

Comment: No shared image. It is just uploaded to the gpu, but i do that before the kernel execution. Kernel is executed via enqueuendrangekernel

Comment: is the 3ms timing only for kernel or copying included?

Comment: no, copying is not included. with opengl it takes not even 1ms somehow

Comment: Could it be delta color compression triggered in opengl somehow?

Comment: Do you need normalized coordinates? could you provide image types and sampler being used?

Comment: how do you measure? using gettime() is not a proper measurement, you should use  CL events to gather profiling info.

Comment: is this 3ms vs 1ms about a single image or average over a series of different images one after another invalidating cache?

Comment: Okay sorry for so much missing information:
1. I use normalized coordinates in order to provide automatic scaling.
2. Image formats: CL_RGBA, CL_UNSIGNED_INT32
3. I use linear filtering, CL_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.
4. For time measuring I use the std::chrono lib and force opencl to finish after executing.
Thanks for far guys ;)

Comment: It could be Nvidia implementing fastpath for opengl while complete path for opencl image accesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilinear interpolation is 2x-3x slower than nearest neighbor way. Are you sure you are not using nearest neighbor in opengl?

What it does in background(by the sampler) is something like:

```
R1 = ((x2 – x)/(x2 – x1))*Q11 + ((x – x1)/(x2 – x1))*Q21

R2 = ((x2 – x)/(x2 – x1))*Q12 + ((x – x1)/(x2 – x1))*Q22

After the two R values are calculated, the value of P can finally be calculated by a weighted average of R1 and R2.

P = ((y2 – y)/(y2 – y1))*R1 + ((y – y1)/(y2 – y1))*R2

The calculation will have to be repeated for the red, green, blue, and optionally the alpha component of.
```

http://supercomputingblog.com/graphics/coding-bilinear-interpolation/

---

Or it is simply Nvidia implemented fastpath for opengl and complete path for opencl image access. For example, for amd, image writes are complete path, smaller than 32bit data accesses are complete path, image reads are fastpath.

---

Another option: Z-order is better suited to compute-divergence of those image data and opencl's non Z-order(suspicious, maybe not) is worse.

Comment: Yup linear sampling was a problem. My kernel computation takes lesser time now. Also not calling finish() helped a lot

Comment: @DaOnlyOwner also it could be the Z-order versus linear 1-d order or square 2-d order for the divergence of pixel data computations. But only when data has non-normalized results.

Answer (score 1):

Division is often expenisve so
I suggest moving calculation of `normalizedCoords` to host side.

On host side:

```
float normalized_x[output_width]; // initialize with [0..output_width-1]/output_width
float normalized_y[output_height]; // initialize with [0..output_height-1]/output_height
```

Change kernel to:

```
#define SETUP_KERNEL(name, operator)\
 __kernel void name(__read_only image2d_t image1,\
                        __read_only image2d_t image2,\
                       __write_only image2d_t output,\
                       global float *normalized_x, \
                       global float *normalized_y, \
                       const sampler_t sampler1,\
                       const sampler_t sampler2,\
                       float opacity)\
{\
    int2 xy = (int2) (get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));\
    float2 normalizedCoords = (float2) (normalized_x[xy.x],normalized_y[xy.y] );\
    float4 pixel1 = read_imagef(image1, sampler1, normalizedCoords);\
    float4 pixel2 = read_imagef(image2, sampler2, normalizedCoords);\
    write_imagef(output, xy, (pixel1 * opacity) operator pixel2);\
}
```

Also you can try not using normalized cooardinates by using the same technique.
This would be more beneficial if the sizes of the input images dont change often.